# Azure function app: Dependencies installed but some are not found

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-function-app

I am using a Dockerfile and requirements.txt in order to setup my azure function app (following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-python) tutorial).
This is my [Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/aLKS13PS) and this is my [requirements.txt](https://pastebin.com/2U00dJ03). After I build the docker image using: `sudo docker build --tag measurekid/mkserverless:v1.0.0 .` I run `sudo docker run -p 8080:80 -it measurekid/mkserverless:v1.0.0` and I get [this error](https://pastebin.com/CEKLWcqJ). The project structure is as followes:

```
|-- project 
   |-- serverless #(which is the azure function root)
      |-- BedPredict 
         |-- __init__.py and more
   |-- bed-coordinates-detection
      |-- bed_pipeline.py (which has the function "mask_pipeline")
```

In my `__init__.py` file I have the following lines:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../bed-coordinates-detection/")
from bed_pipeline import mask_pipeline
```

But as you can see in error message attached above, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bed_pipeline'`.

I have tried following [this troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/recover-python-functions?tabs=vscode#troubleshoot-modulenotfounderror) but I couldn't reach the project files (None of the methods worked).

I am very new to Azure and Azure function app and I have no idea what went wrong. Any ideas? Any response would be super appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per your project structure, you need to go one more level up from `__init__.py` to get `bed-coordinates-detection`. Also in your project structure, the name is `bed-bed-coordinates-detection` (bed twice, is it typo?).

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../../bed-coordinates-detection/")
from bed_pipeline import mask_pipeline
```

By the way, the problem has nothing to do with Azure Function or Docker. You can debug in your local without docker-izing which can easily reveal the issue.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the replay.  Sadly this was only a typo in the post. I fixed it here. Any ideas? 
Btw, how can I debug this locally? using ```func start```?